# Best way to extract the second level domain from the HTTP_Host Variable in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I need to extract only the 2nd level part of the domain from request.servervariables("HTTP_HOST") what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved through a regular expression.

Since the `HTTP_HOST` server variable can contain only valid host names, we don't need to care about *validating* the string, only about finding out its structure. Therefore the regex is kept fairly simple, but would not work reliably in broader contexts.

And the structure is `3.2.1` for third-, second- and first-level (top-level) domains, respectively.

A top-level domain can have 2+ letters (like `.com` or `.de`) or, conceptually, a combination, like `.co.uk`. This is not *technically* a TLD anymore, but I take it that you are not really interested in getting `co` as the second-level domain for many British host names.

So we have

- optional: all kinds of things at the start (sub-domain), a dot = `^(.*?)\.?`
- required: a piece in the middle (second-level domain), a dot = `(\w+)\.`
- required: a short bit (or two short bits) at the end = `(\w{2,}(?:\.\w{2})?)$`

These three things will be captured in groups 1, 2, and 3.

```vb
Dim re, matches, match

Set re = New RegExp

re.Pattern = "^(.*?)\.?(\w+)\.(\w{2,}(?:\.\w{2})?)$"

Set matches = re.Execute( Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") )

If matches.Count = 1 Then
  Set match = matches(0)

  ' assuming "images.res.somedomain.co.uk"
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(0) & "<br>" ' will be "images.res"
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(1) & "<br>" ' will be "somedomain"
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(2) & "<br>" ' will be "co.uk"

  ' assuming  "somedomain.com"
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(0) & "<br>" ' will be ""
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(1) & "<br>" ' will be "somedomain"
  Response.Write match.SubMatches(2) & "<br>" ' will be "com"
Else
  ' You have an IP address in HTTP_HOST
End If
```

Comment: The HTPT_HOST header isn't supposed to include sub-domains. This is nonsense. To parse the subdomain, he would need to use the SERVER_NAME header.

Given the url: http://cdn.domain.co.uk, HTTP_HOST should return "domain.co.uk", while SERVER_NAME should return "cdn.domain.co.uk"

Answer (score 1):

```
If Len(strHostDomain) > 0 Then      
    aryDomain = Split(strHostDomain,".")

    If uBound(aryDomain) >= 1 Then
        str2ndLevel = aryDomain(uBound(aryDomain)-1)
        strTopLevel = aryDomain(uBound(aryDomain))          
        strDomainOnly = str2ndLevel & "." & strTopLevel
    End If
End If
```

works for what I need but it doesn't handle .co.uk or other domains that have two parts expected for the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the difference on a subdomain off my rented serverspace and both http_host and server_name reported back the domain name including the subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

Since HTTP_HOST header only returns the domain (excluding any subdomains), you should be able to do the following:

```
'example: sample.com
'example: sample.co.uk
host = split(request.serverVariables("HTTP_HOST"), ".")
host(0) = "" 'clear the "sample" part

extension = join(host, ".") 'put it back together, ".com" or ".co.uk"
```

Comment: This is nonsense. I don't think you understood the question.